# How to toggle line numbers with a keyboard command in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, you can turn line numbers on and off using the `line_numbers` setting, but there isn't an equivalent `toggle_line_numbers` command you can bind to a keystroke (as there is for, say, `toggle_tabs` to toggle file tabs). So is there another way to configure it so I can toggle line numbers at a keystroke?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As per http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html, it looks like you should be able to do something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args":
        {"setting": "line_numbers"} }
```

Don't forget to add a comma at the end of above code if you are placing anywhere but at the end of the Key Bindings Preferences file.

Comment: Worked for me. To keep all in one line:     { "keys": ["super+5"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "line_numbers"}},

Comment: As a side note: If you want to not only hide the line numbers, but also the extra space, used for example for linter marks or git diffs you can replace `"line_numbers"` by `"gutter"`.